# Pre-Post Entity Images fields missing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

this is my week of missing fields. I had a plugin that was using a post-entity image on creation in crm2011. After moving it to 2013 a lookup field is going missing, causing the plugin to fail. I tried to add remove other fields in the image, some are coming across, while some others are not (it doesn't matter if those fields are custom or default they have the same behaviour). Does anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the question, looks like in 2013, on creation if the field is not on the form (I had a reference in the header), the post image will not contain the actual field value.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer, it is useful information. I do not think that the apology is necessary. It might be something to do with the updated, editable header fields.